# El adverbio "solo" y los pronombres demostrativos sin tilde

Tags: acentuación, adverbios, rae, pronombres-demostrativos

Desde hace un tiempo se realizó un cambio o *corrección* de la gramática del idioma español por parte de la RAE, indicándose que el adverbio `solo` y los pronombres demostrativos ya no deben escribirse con tilde.

Según el artículo [El adverbio solo y los pronombres demostrativos, sin tilde](http://www.rae.es/consultas/el-adverbio-solo-y-los-pronombres-demostrativos-sin-tilde) de la misma RAE, ya no se realiza distinción cuando se usa la palabra `solo` como adverbio de cuando se usa como adjetivo. Lo mismo pasa con los pronombres (`éste`, `ése`, etc.) y los determinantes (`este`, `ese`, etc.).

Los argumentos que dan para eso en el artículo me parecen poco convincentes:

> (...) no cumple el requisito fundamental que justifica el uso de la tilde diacrítica, que es el de oponer palabras tónicas o acentuadas a palabras átonas o inacentuadas formalmente idénticas, ya que tanto solo como los demostrativos son siempre palabras tónicas en cualquiera de sus funciones.

Mis preguntas respecto a esto son tres:

1. Si el uso del tilde en esas palabras no se justificaba, ¿por qué durante tanto tiempo fueron aceptadas de esa forma?
2. En el artículo mencionan que *las posibles ambigüedades pueden resolverse casi siempre por el propio contexto*. Ese *casi siempre* es el que me causa ruido, ¿qué ejemplos existen de esto donde se pueda producir esta ambigüedad? Traté de pensar en alguno pero no lo conseguí.
3. En otras preguntas se ha discutido de la influencia de la RAE sobre el lenguaje y viceversa, ¿Es posible que estas nuevas reglas modifiquen el uso que puedan tener estas palabras en el sentido de cómo se escriben?

Para la última pregunta, en mi caso particular me niego a dejar de escribir la tilde cuando *corresponda*, pero me imagino que en generaciones futuras esto se irá perdiendo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La RAE y ASALE tenían ya como objetivo una regularización y simplificación de la ortografía en el siglo XVIII, como podemos leer en la primera ortografía.

Esta primera estableció un estándar, pero reconoció que había algunas prácticas que ya estaban tan repartidas entre escritores que no sería posible cambiarlas (como ejemplo, *haber* debió ser *haver*, pero siendo una palabra tan frecuente, sería una lucha quijotesca intentar forzar la *v*). Aún así, preveía que a lo largo de tiempo y con revisiones, sería posible tal regularización, hacia una ortografía casi completamente fonética.

Esta palabra fonética es la parte más importante. La verdad es que una reforma lógica, en mi opinión, sería tener *g* como /g/ *siempre* (y *z* /θ/, *c* /k/), para que no tengamos que preocuparnos con estos cambios ortográficos en conjugaciones y sufijaciones, y ya dejar de usar *v* a favor de *b* siempre. No obstante, algo así escrito parecería rarísimo para un lector moderno, ya que representa un salto demasiado fuerte. Y tener dos letras con el mismo sonido por lo menos puede representar fonéticamente la lengua sin tener que recurrir a memorizaciones fonéticas como en inglés.

Digo todo lo antes para intentar explicar la visión de la RAE y ASALE. El castellano, cuando escrito, debe simplemente ser una representación de lo hablado. Si una distinción fonética ya no se hace (por ejemplo, *j/x* o *z/ç* o *s/ss* o *ph/f*), es preferible simplificar, pero siempre que no nos aleje demasiado de la tradición. Los tildes diacríticos no tienen ningún propósito fonético. *Este* y *éste* y *solo* y *sólo* se pronunciaban y se pronuncian igual. Por lo tanto, va el pensamiento, no hay por qué escribir la tilde.

No obstante, palabras como *tú* y *tu* **sí** se pronuncian de forma diferente (una es tónica y otra átona), por lo tanto, como la forma escrita debe reflejar la hablada lo máximo posible, una se tilda y otra no, y esta distinción mantienen la RAE y ASALE.

Estos cambios van a efectuarse con tiempo. Todavía hay alguna gente que rechazan dejar atrás la distinción entre *fue/fué* (pero creo que nadie con menos de 40 años anhela el regreso de aquella tilde). Y la vida sigue, pero más simplificada y sin confusión. Así será con los demostrativos y la palabra *solo*.

Comment: Interesante artículo al respecto: ["Sólo" y la tilde de la nostalgia](http://www.eldiario.es/zonacritica/Solo-tilde-nostalgia_6_601299895.html)

Comment: ¡Y otro! [He ido a la RAE solo para que me convenzan de que 'solo' no lleva tilde nunca](http://verne.elpais.com/verne/2017/01/16/articulo/1484578326_259564.html)

Answer (score 2):

La cruzada que está manteniendo la RAE al respecto de estas acentuaciones es bastante surrealista, desde mi punto de vista. Y, al parecer, desde el punto de vista de mucha gente:

- [Sólo/solo: la tilde que enfrenta a la RAE con los escritores](http://www.abc.es/cultura/20141130/abci-solo-tilde-201411291825.html)
- [La RAE, sola contra el acento del adverbio ‘sólo’](http://www.tallerdeletras.com/la-rae-sola-contra-el-acento-del-adverbio-solo/)

En curioso que en el primer artículo se afirma que esta cruzada la lleva manteniendo la RAE desde mediados del siglo XX. Desde mi punto de vista, las reglas de ortografía siempre han seguido unas reglas claras y específicas que nunca han dejado lugar a la subjetividad. Por ello no entiendo que se pretenda que *solo* se acentúe o no según el hecho de que el escritor piense que puede causar o no ambigüedad.

Un ejemplo sencillo de esta ambigüedad viene en uno de los enlaces de la pregunta:

> Pedro trabaja solo los domingos.

¿Se refiere a que únicamente trabaja los domingos, o a que los domingos trabaja sin compañía?

En todo caso, esta oposición de los escritores puede hacer que la RAE rectifique en un momento dado. Esto es como la pregunta que hice de si en América Latina se pasaría a decir *ratón* en vez de *mouse* porque así lo recomienda la RAE, dependerá de cómo la gente adopte el término (o recomendación). De hecho, ya en 2013 la RAE reconocía que su recomendación de no acentuar nunca *solo*, ni siquiera en caso de ambigüedad, que viene de 2010, [no estaba siendo seguida de forma uniforme](http://www.elmundo.es/elmundo/2013/01/09/cultura/1357735373.html). También concedió que escribir *sólo* no constituye una falta de ortografía.

Comment: Hace un tiempo leí entre los tuits de la RAE, como respuesta a alguien que se quejaba del problema de la ambigüedad, que otras muchas palabras también son ambiguas y no por ello se acentúan. ¿Por qué tratar a *solo* de forma diferente? El ejemplo que dio la RAE en su tuit me pareció muy bueno: *Esta noche voy a tener sexo seguro*.

Comment: @Yay el ejemplo es ciertamente buenísimo. Pero en ese caso, ¿por qué la RAE no se deja de miramientos y dice que no se acentúe en ningún caso, como pasa con *seguro*? ¿Por qué mantiene que se pueda tildar en caso de haber ambigüedad?

Comment: Porque la gente se resiste al cambio. No sé si fue en uno de los artículos que enlazas o en algún otro sitio que leí que la RAE durante un tiempo había o censurado o contemplado censurar el *sólo* con tilde en cualquier caso, pero al final dieron su brazo a torcer, viendo que tildar *sólo* cuando hacía de adverbio tenía una gran popularidad. Habría que ver cómo se queda la cosa en unas cuantas décadas.

Comment: Carlos, creo que aquí estás en un error. La RAE dijo que se podía usar la tilde en caso de ambigüedad en 1960. El cambio reciente consiste en pedir que no se use nunca. Lo que ha encontrado resistencia incluso entre algunos académicos, eso sí es cierto.

Comment: @Gorpik releyendo mi respuesta sí que es cierto que estoy metiendo un baile de fechas, primero hablo de mediados del siglo XX y luego de 2010, sin especificar qué se hizo en cada momento. Voy a tener que corregirla. En todo caso, la respuesta de guifa me gusta más, creo que me ha convencido...

Comment: @CarlosAlejo A mi también. Creo que los dos votos que tiene son el tuyo y el mío :D

Answer (score 2):

Tal vez esto me coloque en la minoría, pero qué le vamos a hacer: yo estoy de acuerdo con el criterio expuesto por la RAE y he dejado de acentuar todas esas palabras.

Suele citarse la posible ambigüedad para oponerse a la supresión de la tilde. Sin embargo, en el lenguaje oral no usamos tilde, ¿cómo hacemos para evitar esa ambigüedad? Pues de la forma correcta: usando construcciones inequívocas y no artificios tipográficos. Voy a tomar prestado el ejemplo que propone Carlos Alejo en su respuesta:

> Pedro trabaja solo los domingos.

¿Cómo evito la ambigüedad? Muy sencillo:

> Los domingos, Pedro trabaja solo. <--> Pedro trabaja solamente los domingos.

Con esta cuestión creo que se ha puesto de manifiesto la resistencia al cambio de las personas. También un tiempo atrás muchas personas se resistían a dejar de usar tilde en los monosílabos, pero hoy a todos nos parece natural escribir *dio*, *fe* en lugar de *dió*, *fé*. Y, ojo, el motivo para no usar tilde puede parecer endeble: ¿por qué establecer una excepción a la regla general, según la cual todas las palabras agudas terminadas en vocal, n o s se acentúan<sup>1</sup>? ¿No es más sencillo y natural usar siempre la regla general? Bien, la RAE propuso que la tilde se usa para indicar en qué sílaba recae el acento prosódico y esto no es necesario con los monosílabos, y los hispanohablantes hemos acabado aceptando con naturalidad este criterio. A mí me parece que los criterios expuestos por la RAE para justificar su oposición a acentuar los demostrativos o la palabra *solo* (y también los que expone para oponerse a acentuar otras palabras como *guion*) son razonables y no me causa ningún problema aceptarlos.

<sup>1</sup> En realidad, la regla es ligeramente más complicada: la n o s final deben ir precedidas también por vocal, n o s. Así, escribimos *camión*, *revés*, *Soláns*, pero *Talarn* o *carnets*.