# Uso de "sólo" o "solo" en la expresión "en un solo valor"

Tags: ortografía, acentuación

En la siguiente frase:

> (...) captura el nivel de concentración en un solo valor (...)

¿Es correcto colocar la palabra "solo" sin acento?

Comment: Relacionado: [El adverbio “solo” y los pronombres demostrativos sin tilde](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17599/14069)

Comment: Como dice @walen en su respuesta, la "nueva" norma dice que solo va siempre sin tilde. Con la norma anterior, llevaba tilde si podía sustituir a "solamente", y en este caso no puede, luego ni lleva, ni llevaba tilde.

Comment: @MikMik no exactamente. La norma anterior en realidad decía que se ponía tilde en enunciados en que pudiera haber ambigüedad, en otro caso no era obligatorio tampoco.

Comment: @blonfu Cierto. Pero eso no quita que, en la pregunta en cuestión, el "solo" no lleva tilde ni con la norma anterior ni con la actual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Desde hace algunos años, la palabra **"solo" se escribe *siempre* sin acento**, da igual el caso.

Aquí tienes la [sección relevante de la Ortografía](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=KnsfTmzfQJcLqQIg).

[En este enlace](http://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/Principales_novedades_de_la_Ortografia_de_la_lengua_espanola.pdf) [PDF] tienes un resumen de los cambios introducidos en la Ortografía en 2010. El referente a "solo" es el punto 5, que copio más abajo.

NOTA: Este es uno de esos casos en los que [lo que dice el DPD ya no es correcto](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Adwesaq4ND64VT09xQ#323), porque la edición en línea es de 2005 y se ha quedado obsoleta para algunas cosas.

> **5. Eliminación de la tilde diacrítica en el adverbio solo y los pronombres demostrativos incluso en casos de posible ambigüedad.**
>
> La palabra solo, tanto cuando es adverbio y equivale a solamente (Solo llevaba un par de monedas en el bolsillo) como cuando es adjetivo (No me gusta estar solo), así como los demostrativos este, ese y aquel, con sus femeninos y plurales, funcionen como pronombres (Este es tonto; Quiero aquella) o como determinantes (aquellos tipos, la chica esa), no deben llevar tilde según las reglas generales de acentuación, bien por tratarse de palabras llanas terminadas en vocal o en -s, bien, en el caso de aquel, por ser aguda y acabar en consonante distinta de n o s.
>
> Aun así, las reglas ortográficas anteriores prescribían el uso de tilde diacrítica en el adverbio solo y los pronombres demostrativos para distinguirlos, respectivamente, del adjetivo solo y de los determinantes demostrativos, cuando en un mismo enunciado eran posibles ambas interpretaciones y podían producirse casos de ambigüedad, como en los ejemplos siguientes: Trabaja sólo los domingos [= ‘trabaja solamente los domingos’], para evitar su confusión con Trabaja solo los domingos [= ‘trabaja sin compañía los domingos’]; o ¿Por qué compraron aquéllos
>   libros usados? (aquéllos es el sujeto de la oración), frente a ¿Por qué compraron aquellos libros usados? (el sujeto de esta oración no está expreso y aquellos acompaña al sustantivo libros).
>
> Sin embargo, ese empleo tradicional de la tilde en el adverbio solo y los pronombres demostrativos no cumple el requisito fundamental que justifica el uso de la tilde diacrítica, que es el de oponer palabras tónicas o acentuadas a palabras átonas o inacentuadas formalmente idénticas, ya que tanto solo como los demostrativos son siempre palabras tónicas en cualquiera de sus funciones. Por eso, a partir de ahora se podrá prescindir de la tilde en estas formas incluso en casos de ambigüedad. La recomendación general es, pues, no tildar nunca estas palabras.
>
> Las posibles ambigüedades pueden resolverse casi siempre por el propio contexto comunicativo (lingüístico o extralingüístico), en función del cual solo suele ser admisible una de las dos opciones interpretativas. Los casos reales en los que se produce una ambigüedad que el contexto comunicativo no es capaz de despejar son raros y rebuscados, y siempre pueden evitarse por otros medios, como el empleo de sinónimos (solamente o únicamente, en el caso del adverbio solo), una puntuación adecuada, la inclusión de algún elemento que impida el doble sentido o un cambio en el orden de palabras que fuerce una única interpretación.